# Match on either an error or an empty result

Tags: error-handling, rust, pattern-matching

I have a function that returns `Result<Vec<&str>, String>` for a list of nodes. My intention is to check for an error or an empty vector to return early, or continue if there there is a list.

This is what I am trying, among other things, but the compiler complains about the type of `x`.

```
let nodes = list_nodes(client, &service);
match nodes {
    Err(e) => {
        println!("Unable to list nodes: {:?}", e);
        return;
    },
    Ok(x) if x.as_slice() == []  => {
        println!("No nodes found for service: {}", service);
        return;
    }
    _ => {}
}
```

The error is:

```
error[E0282]: type annotations needed
  --> src/main.rs:28:18
   |
28 |         Ok(x) if x.as_slice() == []  => {
   |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot infer type for `A`
```

Comment: I think you need to include more code for context. For example, `A` is in the error message, but not in your code example. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @PeterHall, there is no A in my code, what you see is what I get from the compiler, there is no more context I could give.

Comment: @Arkaitz, try `&x == &[]`. Now you are comparing slice reference and an empty array.

Comment: It seems like current Rust stable will use `A` in the error message, while nightly will use `_`, which is less confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is actually that it can't infer the type of `[]`. The type-checker cannot assume that `[]` here has the same type as `x.as_slice()` because the `PartialEq` trait (where `==` comes from) allows instances where the right hand side is of a different type to the left. You can easily solve it by looking at the slice's length instead, or checking if the slice is empty with `is_empty()`:

```
match nodes {
    Err(e) => {
        println!("Unable to list nodes: {:?}", e);
        return;
    },
    Ok(ref x) if x.as_slice().is_empty() => {
        println!("No nodes found for service: {}", service);
        return;
    }
    _ => {}
}
```

Also, taking a reference to `x` (with `ref x` like I've done above) will prevent another error that you're likely to get, avoiding moving `x` when it is still owned by `nodes`.

Comment: Thanks!, I ended up using `Ok(ref x) if x.is_empty()` since there is no need to extract a slice